# How to convert camera coordinates to coordinate-space of scene?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I am trying to find the coordinates of the Camera in the scene I have made but I end up with coordinates in a different system. Coordinates such as (`0.0134094329550862`, which is about `1cm` in the Scene Coordinate System while moving more than that.

I do this to get coordinates:

```
let cameraCoordinates = self.sceneView.pointOfView?.worldPosition

self.POSx = Double((cameraCoordinates?.x)!)
self.POSy = Double((cameraCoordinates?.y)!)
self.POSz = Double((cameraCoordinates?.z)!)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I found the coordinates of the camera and its orientation.

```
func getUserVector() -> (SCNVector3, SCNVector3) {
    if let frame = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame {
        let mat = SCNMatrix4(frame.camera.transform)
        let dir = SCNVector3(-1 * mat.m31, -1 * mat.m32, -1 * mat.m33)
        let pos = SCNVector3(mat.m41, mat.m42, mat.m43)
        return (dir, pos)
    }
    return (SCNVector3(0, 0, -1), SCNVector3(0, 0, -0.2))
}
```